# How do I use the return value of the begin() function as an argument for the eind() function?

Tags: python

How do I use the return value of the `begin()` function as an argument for the `eind()` function?
If I put `bs` as an argument for `eind()` it gives me a `NameError: name 'bs' is not defined`.

```
stations = ["schagen", "heerhugowaard", "alkmaar", "castricum", "zaandam", "amsterdam sloterdijk", "amsterdam centraal", "amsterdam amstel", "utrecht centraal", "’s-hertogenbosch",
            "eindhoven", "weert","roermond", "sittard", "maastricht"]

def begin(stations):
    bs = input("Wat is uw beginstation?: ").lower()
    while bs not in stations:
        print("Dit station komt niet voor in het traject, probeer het nog eens.")
        bs = input("Wat is uw beginstation?: ").lower()

    return bs

def eind(stations, bs):
    bs_nummer = 0
    es_nummer = 0

    for station in stations:
        if station == bs:
            break
        else:
            bs_nummer += 1

    es = input("Wat is uw eindstation?: ").lower()
    while es not in stations:
        print("Dit station komt niet voor in het traject, probeer het nog eens.")
        es = input("Wat is uw eindstation?: ").lower()

    for station in stations:
        if station == es:
            break
        else:
            es_nummer += 1

    if bs_nummer > es_nummer:
        print("Het door uw gekozen eindstation ligt voor het beginstation.")

    print(bs_nummer)
    print(es_nummer)
    
    return es

begin(stations)
eind(stations, "return value of begin function here")
```

Comment: Change the last two rows to `eind(stations, begin(stations))`?

Comment: Save the return from `begin()` in a variable and pass that variable to `eind()`

Comment: Or most simply `bs = begin(stations)`...

Comment: Can you clarify what you are struggling with? This code is using *lots* of return values of functions, what *specific* problem do you have with these two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used as an expression, a function call always resolves to its return value. Simply place the `begin` call where you want its return value:

```
eind(stations, begin(stations))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to understand better you can try to store the `begin(stations)` function in a variable, and then put that variable in the `eind()` function. Like this:

```
x = begin(stations)
eind(stations, x)
```